# Is there a command to show the "handmade" square root algorithm?

Tags: sqrt, xlop

Is there a command to show the product of two integers or the square root of an integer? I know `xlop` package does similar for the division algorithm.

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx

Comment: `xlop` also does products and square roots.  For the latter see `\opgfsqrt`.